# How to improve FFmpeg performance on an older setup when scaling images

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, cpu, gpu, debian-bullseye

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64 on an HP Compaq 8000 Elite CMT PC and it has an old CPU (Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 (2) @ 3.000GHz) and a GPU (GeForce GT 730) that doesn't support video encoding, so don't even consider the fact that I have a GPU.

I have one hundred and nine 5184*3888px JPEG pictures that I want to scale down in FFmpeg. Running this command results in my computer bugging completely:

```
ffmpeg -i *.JPG -vf scale=1296:972 *.JPG
```

I can't move my mouse, escape the program, nothing. This happens after I've confirmed that I want to overwrite files with the same names.

Since I could see no files had been changed after I rebooted my computer, I'm assuming FFmpeg did not output anything before stalling. I've attempted the procedure several times, and I get a frozen computer every time.

How do I tell FFmpeg to "take it slow" rather than filling up my CPU, and could you estimate a good setting that I should use for optimal performance?

Comment: Running `cpulimit -l 50 ffmpeg -i *.JPG -vf scale=1296:972 *.JPG` results in `cpulimit` showing the help dialogue, as though I had entered an incorrect command. Using `cpulimit` version 2.4.

Comment: How much memory does your computer actually have?

Comment: The new versions of FFmpeg has `threads` parameter for `scale` filter. Try: `ffmpeg -i *.JPG -vf scale=1296:972:threads=1 *.JPG`. You may also try `ffmpeg -threads 1 -i *.JPG -vf scale=1296:972:threads=1 -threads 1 *.JPG` or `ffmpeg -threads 1 -filter_threads 1 -i *.JPG -vf scale=1296:972 -threads 1 *.JPG` (limiting the number of threads should solve the problem, unless the RAM is very small).

Comment: Your shell most likely expanded `*.JPG` and the second `*.JPG`. Only the first result from the first `*.JPG` was the option-argument for `-i`. Only the first result from the second `*.JPG` was affected by `-vf scale=1296:972`. 200+ arguments were interpreted as output files. I suspect if the command worked then all the matching files would be overwritten with (possibly processed) content of the first file; or maybe `ffmpeg` would complain `cannot edit existing files in-place`. Anyway your command probably does not do what you want. Use a shell loop and process the files one by one.

Comment: @Mokubai Running `free` returns 8078120 KiB total.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for your comment. I'm still getting a frozen computer, (had to reboot again) so I'm assuming my RAM is also to blame.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sounds like a nice option, although I've never programmed shell scripts before. I could certainly google around for some time, but what would be even better is if you'd kindly give me an example script to get started. ;) Thanks for your response, my the way. It's appreciated.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `for i in *.JPG; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf scale=1296:972 "$i"-scaled.jpg; done` works perfectly. Thanks so much for the tip! God bless.

Comment: @GPWR Now you can answer your own question. There is no need to mention me in the answer. Keep it technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use ImageMagic instead of of FFmpeg.

Why are you using FFmpeg to process images? You are using a tool primarily used for processing video to process static images.

Yes, I know FFmpeg can do what you are attempting to do, but that is not the tool many would use in a case like this.

Just install [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) and run this command:

```
find -E * - maxdepth 1 -type f -iregex '.*\.(JPG|JPEG|PNG|PSD|TIF|TIFF|HEIC)$' |\
    while read FULL_IMAGE_PATH
    do
        convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -resize "1296x972>" -quality 100 "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}" "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}";
    done
```

This is a basic `find` script I use for image resizing and it works great!

And if this script still chokes your system, use [`sleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) to pause each loop of the command. Here is a modified version of the above command that adds a simple 1 second pause between each loop.

```
find -E * - maxdepth 1 -type f -iregex '.*\.(JPG|JPEG|PNG|PSD|TIF|TIFF|HEIC)$' |\
    while read FULL_IMAGE_PATH
    do
        convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -resize "1296x972>" -quality 100 "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}" "${FULL_IMAGE_PATH}";
    sleep 1;
    done
```

Or, if that stuff seems to complicated to use — it’s simply more robust and flexible in my humble opinion — you can just use this variant of the `for` loop you are using but with ImageMagick instead like this:

```
for i in *.JPG;
do
    convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -resize "1296x972>" -quality 100 "$i" "$i"-scaled.jpg;
done
```

Comment: This looks like a very fine answer, but what is the advantage of using ImageMagic over FFmpeg? The script seems much longer. (I know, longer isn't necessarily less efficient. It's just an observation.)

Comment: The benefit is ImageMagick is what is traditionally used to process images and FFmpeg is use to process video. Thus speed and quality might be different. As for the script being longer, it is just me wanting to be more thorough in processing various image formats. For example, this would probably work just as well in your case: `for i in *.JPG; do convert -density 72 -units PixelsPerInch -resize "1296x972>" -quality 100 "$i" "$i"-scaled.jpg; done`. Try it out and see!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Indeed I tried it and it works just fine. I hadn't ever really used ImageMagic extensively before. (Well, I did indirectly use it, but not via Bash.) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to use a simple single-line Bash for-loop, as follows:

```
for i in *.JPG; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf scale=1296:972 "$i"-scaled.jpg; done
```

The `for i in *.JPG;` part can be translated to English as: "for all files ending in '.JPG' (by the way, assign the rest of the name to the variable *i* )." The `do ffmpeg -i "$i"` can be translated as: "do this: call ffmpeg and input all files having a name which corresponds to *i*'s value, that is, all files ending in .JPG." The `-vf scale=1296:972` part translates to: "apply the 'scale' video filter, using the dimensions 1296 by 972 (in pixels, by default)." The `"$i"-scaled.jpg` part translates to "all the outputed files should be named with their original name, followed by the string '-scaled.jpg'." The final part, `done`, should not be left out, as this is what ends the for loop, resulting in the termination of the execution of the Bash command.

Comment: A "stack overflow" is something very specific and this is not what happens here. A "stack overflow" can occur even with a minimal amount of occupied memory and the result is simply a crash of the program, nothing freezes. My best guess here is that your initial command fills up the memory one way or another, and then the OS is using the swap file. Once swapping, the whole OS becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Besides, having more RAM would not be a solution at all: your initial command was flawed and can definitely not give the expected result.

Comment: @PierU Thanks for highlighting that. I removed the misinformation from my answer.